# SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. Java.Spring MVC

Tags: java, sql, spring, arraylist, resultset

I'm using Prepared Statement for my `SELECT` query. After that i'm trying to get my informating from `ResultSet` and to put it into `ArrayList`.
I'm doing it into Result Set loop but i'm getting an error `java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`.
I tried to close it with `rs.close()` but it gave me same error. Here is my method. Help pls!

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Users> listUsersSort(Integer weight, String gender, String place, Integer ageTo, String currentUser) {
    System.out.println(weight + gender + place + ageTo + currentUser);
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    boolean weightFlag = false;
    boolean genderFlag = false;
    boolean placeFlag = false;
    boolean ageToFlag = false;
    int iterator = 0;
    List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<Users>();
    String selectSQL = "select*from users where users.enabled = ?";
    if (weight < 40 == false) {
        String weightParam = " AND users.weight <= ?";
        selectSQL = selectSQL.concat(weightParam);
        weightFlag = true;
        System.out.println(selectSQL);
    }
    if (gender.isEmpty() == false) {
        String genderParam = " AND  users.gender LIKE ?";
        selectSQL = selectSQL.concat(genderParam);
        genderFlag = true;
    }

    if (place.isEmpty() == false) {
        String placeParam = " AND users.place LIKE ?";
        selectSQL = selectSQL.concat(placeParam);
        placeFlag = true;
        // query = query.concat(placeParam);
    }
    if (ageTo < 19 == false) {
        String age = " AND users.age <= ?";
        selectSQL = selectSQL.concat(age);
        ageToFlag = true;
    }
    String withoutUser = " AND users.username NOT LIKE ?";
    selectSQL = selectSQL.concat(withoutUser);
    System.out.println("FINAL QUERY IS: " + selectSQL);
    Connection con = getConnection();
    try {

        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(++iterator, true);
        if (weightFlag)
            preparedStatement.setInt(++iterator, weight);

        if (genderFlag)
            preparedStatement.setString(++iterator, gender);

        if (placeFlag)
            preparedStatement.setString(++iterator, place);

        if (ageToFlag)
            preparedStatement.setInt(++iterator, ageTo);

        preparedStatement.setString(++iterator, currentUser);

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Users userrs = new Users();
        while (rs.next()) {             
            userrs.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            userrs.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            userrs.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
            userrs.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
            userrs.setWeight(rs.getInt("weight"));
            userrs.setHeight(rs.getInt("height"));
            userrs.setSport(rs.getString("sport"));
            userrs.setSport(rs.getString("place"));
            usersList.add(userrs);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return usersList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the connection will also close the prepared statement.

You should only close the connection after finishing your business with the resultset.

Your code should look like:

```
Connection dbConnection=null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  dbConnection = getConnection();
  preparedStatement = dbConnection.preparedStatement(...);

  ... bind variables to preparedStatement ...

  rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  ... work with result set ...

} finally {
  if (rs!=null)
    rs.close();
  if (preparedStatement!=null)
    preparedStatement.close();
  if (dbConnection!=null)
    dbConnection.close();
}
```

Edit: in Java7 you would write:

```
try (Connection dbConnection = getConnection();
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.preparedStatement(...)) {

  ... bind variables to preparedStatement ...

  try (ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

    ... work with result set ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Um, try-with-resources? No need for finally.

Comment: I **do** assume that he is using Java 7, especially because 6 is officially at end of life.

Comment: Java 6 is alive and kicking thanks to android. (We're required to write a lot of portable code between Windows, Linux and Android, so Java 6 is our go to...)

Comment: In any case I added both options.

Comment: You would probably want to keep the connection alive longer. It's a waste to create a connection for each query.

Comment: Same goes for prepared statements. They are reusable. You prepare them once, and then just bind and execute them over and over. Saves time, computation and traffic for both you and the sql server.